Where is the inflection point here in this elbow chart?
Where do you think is the inflection point on this chart?


An inflection is where a curve changes from convex to concave or conversely. An elbow is where there is an apparent kink, a marked change in slope. I wouldn't infer either in your case, which is a matter of judgment. Scientifically the idea that variation is a continuum without definite clusters is often highly plausible.

Show us the data. As it stands, there doesn't seem to be an inflection point...

First of all, why do you want to identify an inflection point?

I don't see an inflection point (which I think you're using a synonym for "elbow", "knee", or "kink", but as others have pointed out has a different technical meaning ...). As the Wikipedia page on the 'elbow method' says,

The elbow method is considered both subjective and unreliable. In many practical applications, the choice of an "elbow" is highly ambiguous as the plot does not contain a sharp elbow.

You could look at some of the other methods suggested on Wikipedia for choosing the number of clusters.
(I might pick k=3 or k=4 because at least the slope seems higher below than above that range ...)

The inflection point is to be found in the curve of the changes. An elbow shaped curve doesn't have an inflection point, but its derivative does.
If clusters matter, then you typically have big changes in the effects (change in cost) of adding a cluster until some point when the clusters are not adding anything meaningful and the effect is just reducing random noise which is much smaller. Then the change in the effect drops after which it remains at some level again, and that gives an inflection point.
You have a smooth curve where the transitions are much less clear without a sudden drop in the effect of adding a cluster. So at least there is not a big change in the effect of adding another cluster, as a function of the number of clusters already used. This can happen when either all clusters are meaningful, or when none are meaningful.
You can use simulations to find out what sort of cost values would be expected when you do not have clusters.
